# to serve a downloadable link to a file(pdf or word doc) in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In the application the user has the option of downloading the paper that is stored in the media folder within the app's directory. Now how do I get the option of downloading that paper working. The present code that I've provided below takes me to the URL from the current html page -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorViewSubmission/papers/some.pdf
```

The actual file is stored in media/papers/some.pdf

Can someone tell me how do i get the download link working here?

## in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

## in my template

```
<td><a href ="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{i.paper.url}}" class="btn btn btn-success" role="button">Download Paper</a></td>
```

Comment: `{{ i.paper.url }}` should be enough to get the full url.

Comment: yeah ! I just got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a proper answer: `{{ i.paper.url }}` should be enough to get the full url.